# list comprehension that a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo db cusor object that get converted into a list. The list is a list of dictionaries however when I go to access the value I get this error below:

```
 in <listcomp>
    for e in app.db.entries.find_one({})
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The code is listed here:

```py
import datetime

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@MicroBlog.0oxexa.mongodb.net/test")

app.db = client.MicroBlog

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])

@app.route("/home", methods = ["GET", "POST"])

def home():
    if request.method == "POST":

        content = request.form["content"]

        formattedDate =datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        app.db.entries.insert_one({"content": content, "date": formattedDate})

        mongo_entries_with_date = [
        (
        e["content"],
        e["date"],
        datetime.datetime.strptime(e["date"], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%b %d")
        )
        for e in app.db.entries.find_one({})
        ]

        return render_template("home.html", entries = mongo_entries_with_date), 201

return render_template("home.html"), 200
```

Comment: `find_one` will return a `dict`. When you iterate over `dict` you iterate over keys, so `e` is a string. Probably you want to use find instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `e = app.db.entries.find_one({})` on the line before `mongo_entries_with_date` and get rid of the square brackets. or put square brackets around `app.db.entries.find_one({})`.

Answer (score 0):

This way worked as well by changing app.db.entries.find_one({}) to app.db.entries.find({}) with the rest of the code as is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).